# DELETE rows which are not referenced in other table

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3, delete

I have two tables in a PostgreSQL 9.3 database: Table `link_reply` has a foreign key named `which_group` pointing to table `link_group`.

I want to delete all rows from `link_group` where no related row in `link_reply` exists. Sounds basic enough but I've been struggling with it.

Will it be something simple like this (not working)?

```
DELETE FROM link_group WHERE link_reply = NULL;
```

Comment: do you have a DDL for everyone to look at?

Comment: Take a look at the MINUS operator. You have to specify a field in links_reply.

Comment: `DELETE FROM links_group 
USING links_group AS lg
LEFT JOIN links_reply AS lr ON
   lg.col= lr.some_other_col
WHERE links_reply.some_other_col IS NULL `

Comment: I had a similar question, which also takes concurrency in account. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251875.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html)

> There are two ways to delete rows in a table using information
>   contained in other tables in the database: **using sub-selects, or
>   specifying additional tables in the `USING` clause**. Which technique is
>   more appropriate depends on the specific circumstances.

Bold emphasis mine. Using information that is ***not*** contained in another table is a tad bit tricky, but there are easy solutions. From the arsenal of standard techniques to ...

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

... a `NOT EXISTS` anti-semi-join is probably simplest and most efficient for `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM link_group lg
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM link_reply lr
   WHERE  lr.which_group = lg.link_group_id
   );
```

Assuming (since table definitions are not provided) `link_group_id` as column name for the primary key of `link_group`.

The technique [@Mihai commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134221/getting-basic-postgresql-query-right#comment252132_134221) works as well (applied correctly):

```
DELETE FROM link_group lg
USING  link_group      lg1
LEFT   JOIN link_reply lr ON lr.which_group = lg1.link_group_id
WHERE  lg1.link_group_id = lg.link_group_id
AND    lr.which_group IS NULL;
```

But since the table expression in the `USING` clause is joined to the target table (`lg` in the example) with a `CROSS JOIN`, you need another instance of the same table as stepping stone (`lg1` in the example) for the `LEFT JOIN`, which is less elegant and typically slower.