# Select children of product, with no other active parents

Tags: postgresql

Given these two tables in Postgres 9.6:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  status text
);

CREATE TABLE products_m_products (
  parent_product_id bigint REFERENCES product,
  child_product_id  bigint REFERENCES product
);
```

*How to select all **active children** of a given product that have **no other active parent**?*

As I understand it needs to be something like this:

1. Get all children of product *A*.
2. Get all the parents of the children.
3. Filter out all non active (`status` = 'DELETED') parents.
4. Count the remaining parents for each children.
5. Keep children whose parent count is 1 or less.

But how do I put this into a query?

I tried this:

```
select distinct child, parent 
from product as child, 
     product as parent,
     (select child_product_id 
          from products_m_products 
          where parent_product_id = 1337) as children,
     products_m_products as parents
where child.id = children.child_product_id 
    AND parents.child_product_id = children.child_product_id 
    AND child.product_status = 'ACTIVE'
    AND parents.parent_product_id = parent.id 
    AND parent.product_status = 'ACTIVE';
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct.

We can assume that *A* is active, but it should be excluded from the final result since *A* will be deactivated.

Answer (score 3):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT child.child_product_id
FROM   products_m_products child
JOIN   product             c_prod ON c_prod.id = child.child_product_id
WHERE  child.parent_product_id = 1337     -- user input here
AND    c_prod.status = 'ACTIVE'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT
   FROM   products_m_products parent
   JOIN   product             p_prod ON p_prod.id = parent.parent_product_id
   WHERE  parent.child_product_id = child.child_product_id
   AND    p_prod.status = 'ACTIVE'
   AND    parent.parent_product_id <> 1337  -- same user input
   );
```

The anti-semi-join with `NOT EXISTS` only keeps children with no *other* active parent than the given *A*. This query does not care whether the given parent `A` is active itself.

Should be as fast as possible.

There are several basic techniques to check there is no related row in another table:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Related answer using a `LEFT JOIN`:

- [DELETE rows which are not referenced in other table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134221/delete-rows-which-are-not-referenced-in-other-table/134240#134240)

Comment: i added more details. i hope it helps.

Comment: @MarkoTaht: Consider the updated answer.