# Deletion of orphaned rows in a violation-free & non-blocking manner: predictive order of execution of predicates in case of double-checked locking

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, locking, concurrency, cascade

I have tables `person` and `toy`. There is a foreign key `person.favorite_toy_id` from `person` to `toy`. This foreign key is declared as `ON DELETE RESTRICT`. I now want to delete all toys which are no longer declared as favorite in a violation-free and non-blocking manner:

- I want to delete as much orphaned toys as possible, while avoiding a foreign key violation because we attempt to delete a toy which is still in use.
- I do not want to wait for other ongoing transactions, which are possibly introducing a reference to a toy (which requires a *key share lock*) or simply updating a toy (which requires a *(no key) update lock*), to finish. Both lock types block our *update lock* request, required to delete the toy.

The first, naive approach would be:

```
delete from toy
where       not exists(select 1 from person where person.favorite_toy_id = toy.id)
```

This will not work in a concurrent environment: after the completion of the `not exists` predicate, a concurrent transaction could declare the toy in question as favorite. In such case, we end up with a foreign key violation. Also, as said, I prefer this delete to happen in a non-blocking fashion, which is not attempted in this query.

So, my second approach in attempt to avoid this foreign key violation and any blocking is:

```
delete from toy
where       toy.id in
            (
              select toy.id
              from   toy
              where  not exists(select 1 from person where person.favorite_toy_id = toy.id)
              for update skip locked
            )
```

However, this doesn't solve the requirement to avoid the foreign key violation, because the lock is taken after the evaluation of the `not exists` predicate. So there is a small chance that we attempt to delete a toy which is still marked as favorite, resulting in a foreign key violation.

My third attempt to fix this is the following:

```
delete from toy
where       toy.id in
            (
              select toy.id
              from   toy
              where  not exists(select 1 from person where person.favorite_toy_id = toy.id)
              for update skip locked
            ) and
            not exists(select 1 from person where person.favorite_toy_id = toy.id)
```

This applies double-checked locking (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). This would work if and only if we have the guarantee that the subquery is always evaluated before the additional `not exists` predicate. As far as I know, there is no such guarantee.

My question is rather educational: can this be solved in a pure SQL query? We can of course implement this in a `plpgsql` function as shown below, but let's assume we want to solve this in one single plain SQL query.

```
create function prune_toys() returns void as
$$
declare
  _id int;
begin
  for _id in select toy.id from toy where not exists(...) for update skip locked loop
    delete from toy where toy.id = _id and not exists(...);
  end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

In all this, I assume the read committed transaction isolation level.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a business process / UI race. It is often solved by deprecating / hiding values for a period before deleting and/or not accepting them as valid anymore.

One approach would be to add a `DateDeprecated` column to toys. Update it to the current date when you check and nobody has this toy as a favorite. Clear the field if/when the toy is selected as a favorite. In the UI don't show/list deprecated toys at all or don't show toys deprecated for a certain period of time like over 7 days. At some point delete long deprecated toys, say after they have been deprecated for 14 days.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't know if this would help but using negative logic like "NOT EXISTS" means that every row has to be examined (locked) to determine if it meets the criteria. If you can find a way to make it positive logic like "EXISTS", it should only evaluate the rows that qualify both speeding up the query and reducing the locks. Just a thought...